# Can DataMapper use a true Enumerable column?

Tags: ruby, enums, datamapper

By default, DataMapper creates Integer columns in the database for Enum properties ([docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types.html)). If you store the 2nd value in the Enum's array, it stores a 2.

Is there a way to get it to use a true Enum column?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the sources of `Enum`, copy/paste, and patch it accordingly. It should already overwrite all methods that are needed, so it shouldn't be too hard. Just remember that not all backends might support a true `Enum` type, but it should be good enough if you know yours does support it.